# Can I have beta test build simultaniously with production one?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

We have released our app in the google play recently.After the release we made some fixes to make app run on older android 4.4 devices.Testing with emulator is inadequate.Can we have alpha/beta test build simultaniously with production?If yes how then testers will get test version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, there is a section under `Release management` called `App releases`. Here you can upload apks to alpha or beta for users to test. See scrteenshot for reference

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know it.I'm just confused google play generates for test builds same url as for production.I'm afraid testers will receive production build instead of test one or even worse - test build will replace production build.

Comment: You mean you want users to have 2 different versions of your app on their device, one for testing and one for production? This is unfortunately not possible. The only option I see is to upload another app to the Play Store under a different package name.

Comment: No testers our build targeted on don't have our app at all.I'd like they were able to get from google play alpha build as well as production one.The problem is they both have same url( at least it was so before we went live)

Comment: If users signed up for beta tests, they will only get builds for beta tests, it depends on the apk version code. For example you upload apk with version code 10 to beta test, and your production code is 9, then users that signed up for beta tests will get version 10, and normal users won't see an update. If you move version 10 to production, then everyone sees it.

Comment: damn it doesn't let me to rollout test build because production build is conflicting with it here is what it says for production build:`This APK will not be served to any users because it is completely shadowed by one or more APKs with higher version codes.`

Comment: You have to increase the version code to a higher number than the production one

Comment: of course here how it looks like:https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqxhe2so39c4oyt/screenshot%20%282%29.png?dl=0

Comment: 36 is production,37 is test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142144/discussion-between-denny-and-undefined).